"noUnusedLocals" in tsconfig.json report as Error instead of Warning (nvim + tsserver LSP)
Adding "noUnusedLocals" in tsconfig.json makes it report unused vars as Error instead of Warning (using nvim + tsserver LSP)
What did I try? Well I tried so many things that I don't know anymore :)
I know there is a discussion in the official repo, so this is not a new issue.
However VScode is able to report the unused vars as Warning only, tsserver report as Error. Wasn't able to find out why yet or how to tweak this.
Any suggestion?

ps: I found some similar discussions here but focused on VScode, one of those discussions even mention about a hack to be done on VSCode but I couldn't mimic that in Nvim.
